# Find beginning and end of a string

Tags: python, string, substring, prefix

Lets say I have a list of words called "words" and want to print either what they begin or end with with the functions endch and begch, something like this:

```
words = ["prison", "group", "breakfast"]
for i in words:
  print(i.begch(3))
  print(i.endch(2))
```

This would result in showing: **pri on gro up bre st**.

Which function / code does that (I want something better than getting characters one by one from start or end and concatenating them) ? "str.startswith" requires you to already know the prefix you're looking for and prefix finding functions find the prefix common for all words.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for slicing?

```
for i in words:
    print(i[:3], i[-2:], end=' ')
```

Output:

```
pri on gro up bre st
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use string slices:

```
words = ["prison", "group", "breakfast"]
for i in words:
    print(i[:3], i[-2:])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    def begch(str, idx):
        return str[ : idx]
    def endch(str, idx):
        return str[-idx : ]
    words = ["prison", "group", "breakfast"]
    for i in words:
        print(begch(i,3))
        print(endch(i,2))
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.